# Criar um Crud com uma tabela com relacionamento N para N C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho essa estrutura e queria saber como faço um CRUD com um relacionamento N-> N
Minhas dúvidas :
1 - Como listar os participantes de um determinado evento.
2 - Como incluir um participante em um evento.

Comment: compartilhe como montou as entidades e o dbset dessa estrutura no EF

Comment: public partial class EventoParticipante
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int IdEvento { get; set; }
        public int IdParticipante { get; set; }

        public virtual Evento IdEventoNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Participante IdParticipanteNavigation { get; set; }
    }    public virtual DbSet<EventoParticipante> EventoParticipante { get; set; }

Comment: edite a pergunta com essas informações